# When cedet semantic parsing c header files of my system, here comes "Idle Parse Error":

Tags: c, emacs, mingw, cedet

> No method definition: semanticdb-add-reference, (nil (\"stdio.h\"
>   include (:system-flag t) (unlink-copy-hook
>   (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays) link-hook
>   (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays) secondary-overlays (# #) unlink-hook
>   (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays) dependency-file
>   \"d:/MinGW/include/stdio.h\") #))"

I use `mingw` in *windows 7* system, `c.c` is the file name, and there are two sentence in `init.el` which are relevant to the problem:

> (semantic-add-system-include "D:/MinGW/include" 'c-mode)
>   (setq semantic-c-dependency-system-include-path "D:/MinGW/include")

Comment: Please consider formatting your post to ease readability

Comment: sorry, but the first paragraph is the original error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"M-x customize" then
search "Global Semanticdb Minor Mode" then
toggle on it

Answer (score 1):

The include path you are setting should be a list, such as:

```
(setq semantic-c-dependency-system-include-path '("d:/MinGW/include"))
```

but you don't need that line if you are using `semantic-add-system-include`.

While I haven't tried it, you can probably skip doing either of the above by instead using `semantic-gcc-setup` and ask your minGW compiler.  Just make sure a command "gcc" is on your exec-path when you start Emacs, and it will be automatically detected.

No one has reported this working or not working for MinGW, so if it works out, let us know.

Comment: Sorry, I have given it a try, but it don't take effect. I can compile the program while the problem exists.Furthermore, how to use "semantic-gcc-setup"? There is no response when "M-x semantic-gcc-setup"

Comment: I execute (semantic-gcc-setup) in lisp-interaction-mode, It return "Nil". And when I execute (semantic-gcc-query "gcc" "-v"), here comes:Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Comment: The problem occurs again when I open "flyspell.el", here comes:`Idle Parse Error: "#<buffer flyspell.el> - No method definition: semanticdb-add-reference, (nil (\"ispell\" include nil (dependency-file \"e:/Fire_Workspace/emacs_24/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el\") #<overlay from 1374 to 1391 in flyspell.el>))"`

Comment: "flyspell.el" is in "<emacs main entry>/lisp/textmodes/flyspell.el"

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like a debugger is needed.  M-x semantic-debug-idle-function, or perhaps M-x semantic-debug-idle-work-function depending on where the error is.  Just try both till you find it.  The stack should be helpful in showing where this problem is derived from.  This debug step is unrelated to getting the system include path setup.  For that after you run the setup fcn, you can do M-x semantic-c-describe-environment to see if all those settings got setup for you.  If so, on that from you'll be all set.

Comment: I finally resolve the problem by turning on the “Global Semantic Minor Mode” using “M-x customize”. How stupid I'm, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Semi-related rant: `ffap-c` does not take this variable into consideration.